# How can I open the Active Directory 'Select Users, Computers, or Groups' search dialog and pass the selection(s) as a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In various Active Directory menus, there is a dialog box to search for certain AD objects like Computers, Users and Groups.

One place this can be found is on the **Members** tab for a group when the **Add** button is clicked.

Is there a way to invoke this dialog with a Powershell or other command, and then pass the selection back to the script as a variable?

[image: How to find the menu]

[image: Screen shot of the dialog]

Comment: Why not simply using the ActiveDirectory cmdlets as e.g. [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser)?

Comment: I am building a GUI for non-technical users.  I can use Get-ADUser, or Get-ADComputer but the users are already familiar with this GUI.

There is a similar 'Find Users, Contacts and Groups' GUI that can be opened with the command:

`Rundll32 dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow`

But this one doesn't appear to be able to pass any selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with Windows Forms:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-7.3

You can also hide the PS windows with:

```
# https://www.systanddeploy.com/2018/12/create-your-own-powershell.html
$Global:windowShowing = $false
$windowcode = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
$asyncwindow = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $windowcode -name Win32ShowWindowAsync -namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
$hwnd = (Get-Process -PID $pid).MainWindowHandle
$null = $asyncwindow::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 0)
```